# Sort posts in WordPress by list of author IDs / Combine two loops

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to sort a list of posts based on the IDs of a few authors.
The posts from this authors should appear on top of the post list (in alphabetical order). After these posts, the rest of the posts should also appear in alphabetical order.

I found no easy way to sort by a list of authors.

At the moment I've a list of author IDs in an array. The code for that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'numberposts'   => -1,
    ) );

    $ids = array();

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <?php
            $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
            array_push( $ids, get_the_author_meta('ID', $post_author_id) );
        ?>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>

<?php print_r($ids); ?>
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 545 [1] => 543 [2] => 542 [3] => 538 [4] => 6 )
```

Now I've my normal WordPress Loop which looks like this:

```
<?php

$wp_query = new WP_Query();

$wp_query->query(
    array(
       'post_type'      => 'post',
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => '-1',
       'orderby'        => 'title',
       'order'          => 'ASC',
    )
); ?>

<?php global $wp_query; if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?><?php the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

I didn't found a way in the Class Reference (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) to order by a list of author IDs. Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: You want to order by Author ID so it would be: 6, 538, 542, 543, 545? Or You want to push some specific author to top?

Comment: No, I want to display the posts from the authors (6, 538, 542, 543, 545) on top of the loop in alphabetical order. the order of the author IDs isn't relevant.